# How to access sitemap from custom helper (not in config.rb)

Tags: ruby, middleman

Working on some [custom defined helper classes](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/helpers/#custom-defined-helpers) for middleman I find it difficult to access middleman's resources.sitemap. I wanted to write testcases for my helpers, so passing in the resources and it's sitemap will not be working.

Is there any way to access the middleman resources from "external" code?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Doesn't `sitemap.resources` work for you? Please provide the code that is failing.